# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.boom.geolocationbased.MapView.getFragmentManager

Tags: android

I am new in android programming. I am working on Google Maps Api.
I have followed all of the steps that how to integrate Googel Api into a project and how to add google play services as a referenced library.

But whenI try to run my project into my device the it shows me this error.

```
10-18 18:19:04.742: E/AndroidRuntime(8003): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com.boom.geolocationbased.MapView.getFragmentManager
```

My manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.boom.geolocationbased"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission
  android:name="com.boom.geolocationbased.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.boom.geolocationbased.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name="com.boom.geolocationbased.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyDHe4z6aw_UZbOM9fSLzucg_UfaOoDuJic"/>
    <meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <service android:name="GPSTracker"></service>
    <activity android:name="MapView"></activity>

</application>

</manifest>

and here is my xml file for my mapactivity

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

And the code where I got an error

```
try{
     if(googleMap == null){
         MapFragment fm = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().
                 findFragmentById(R.id.map);
         googleMap = fm.getMap();

     }
```

Please can anyone help me find out what is wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the function scope exists?

Comment: Yes! it got exception over this code that i have mention above in my question.

Comment: i have wrote this code into the oncreate method is it ok or i have to do something else?

Comment: Are you using a MapFragment or a MapView?

Comment: i am using MapFragment.

Answer (score 1):

To get the googleMap, try this instead:

```
GoogleMap googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: i have done this too.... but every times i got this error.. is there any problem with my google services library?

Comment: No obvious reasons but change the way you specify names like "MapView" to "com.boom.geolocationbased.MapView" or ".MapView" and try not to use keywords when defining custom names for activities.